# How to handle Material UI Drawer open and close from a single button/icon in React Functional Component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, webhooks

I want to handle the Material UI Drawer *Open and Close* through a **single** button in **React Functional Component.**

```
 const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
   setOpen(true);
 };

 const handleDrawerClose = () => {
   setOpen(false);
 };
```

```
 <IconButton
   color="inherit"
   aria-label="open drawer"
   onClick= ****
   edge="start"
   className={clsx(classes.menuButton)}
 >
   <MenuIcon />
 </IconButton>
```

Comment: You don't need `clsx` for one class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just add one function toggleButton like this:

```
const toggleButton = () => {
  setOpen(preState => !preState);
}

onClick ={toggleButton}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about toggling based on the existing state?

`const handleDrawerToggle = () => { setOpen(!open);}`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using hooks, then you only need to add [usage of `useState` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) in your component function:

```
const [isDropDownOnen, setDropDownOnen] = useState(false);
const handleDrawerClick = () => {
   setDropDownOnen(!isDropDownOnen);
 };

return (<IconButton
   color="inherit"
   aria-label="open drawer"
   onClick={handleDrawerClick}
   edge="start"
   className={clsx(classes.menuButton)}
 >
   <MenuIcon />
 </IconButton>);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. He didn't post the hook declaration as it's obvious he's using a hook.

Comment: @Yatrix yes, sorry. Forgot to update actual click handler

Comment: `onClick={()=>handleDrawerClick()}` is creating an unnecessary anonymous function. Just set it to `onClick={handleDrawerClick}`

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a separate handler, you can do it inline:

```
<IconButton
   color="inherit"
   aria-label="open drawer"
   onClick= {()=> setOpen(!open)}
   edge="start"
   className={classes.menuButton}
 >
   <MenuIcon />
 </IconButton>
```

If the handler gets complicated, then I'd extract it out into a function just to keep the code tidier and easier to read.